# R data.table operators on lists

Tags: r, list, data.table, operators

What is the correct way to apply data.table operators on a list of data.tables? For example, in base R, we can subset each data.frame in a list of data.frames with: lapply(df, "[", 1:3, TRUE). What would be the correct approach for data.tables?

```
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(year = seq(1975, 1980), name = c("Frank", "Tony", "Edward")))

df <- lapply(1975:1979, function(t) df[with(df, t <= year & year <= t + 1), TRUE])

lapply(df, `[`, 1:3, TRUE)

library(data.table)

dt <- lapply(df, setDT)

lapply(dt, function(x) x[1:3])
```

Comment: What is the issue with the last line of code

Comment: No issue. It's just not very elegant compared to the data.frame operator. I was hoping for something nicer.

Comment: you should try `lapply(dt,\`[\`,1:3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to subset the data.table rows, an option is also `head`

```
lapply(dt, head, 3)
```

---

Or add a `,`.  It is better to name the arguments when we don't use anonymous functions as it is evaluated based on the order of arguments if there is no name.  If we check `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

`drop = TRUE` seems to be the case for the TRUE value in the OP's data.frame index subsetting.  But, with `data.table`, there are many arguments before the `drop`

```
x[i, j, by, keyby, with = TRUE,
  nomatch = getOption("datatable.nomatch", NA),
  mult = "all",
  roll = FALSE,
  rollends = if (roll=="nearest") c(TRUE,TRUE)
             else if (roll>=0) c(FALSE,TRUE)
             else c(TRUE,FALSE),
  which = FALSE,
  .SDcols,
  verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose"),                   # default: FALSE
  allow.cartesian = getOption("datatable.allow.cartesian"),   # default: FALSE
  drop = NULL, on = NULL]
```

We could have two `,` for the `j` and `by` or as @Onyambu mentioned in the comments, we can simple use the index as the row index is the first argument

```
lapply(dt, "[", 1:3, ,)
#[[1]]
#   year  name
#1: 1975 Frank
#2: 1976 Frank
#3: 1975  Tony

#[[2]]
#   year  name
#1: 1976 Frank
#2: 1977 Frank
#3: 1976  Tony

#[[3]]
#   year  name
#1: 1977 Frank
#2: 1978 Frank
#3: 1977  Tony

#[[4]]
#   year  name
#1: 1978 Frank
#2: 1979 Frank
#3: 1978  Tony

#[[5]]
#   year  name
#1: 1979 Frank
#2: 1980 Frank
#3: 1979  Tony
```